# Aurelia Kendo Bridge and Aurelia .Net Core Spa Project

Tags: kendo-ui, webpack, aurelia

I have created a new Aurelia /.Net Core/Typescript project using the .Net CLI command:

```
dotnet new aurelia
```

This works great. Now I want to use the Aurelia Kendo Bridge plugin with this project.

The .Net Core template for Aurelia uses Webpack so I have been trying to follow the instructions covering installation for Webpack here: http://aurelia-ui-toolkits.github.io/demo-kendo/#/installation

I have done the following steps:

1. Installed the Kendo Core npm package:

   `npm install kendo-ui-core jquery --save`
2. Installed Aurelia Kendo Bridge:

   `npm install aurelia-kendoui-bridge --save`
3. Included these npm packages in the entry node of the webpack.config.vendor.js file:

   `entry: {
           vendor: [
               'aurelia-event-aggregator',
               'aurelia-fetch-client',
               'aurelia-framework',
               'aurelia-history-browser',
               'aurelia-logging-console',
               'aurelia-pal-browser',
               'aurelia-polyfills',
               'aurelia-route-recognizer',
               'aurelia-router',
               'aurelia-templating-binding',
               'aurelia-templating-resources',
               'aurelia-templating-router',
               'bootstrap',
               'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
               'jquery',
               'kendo-ui-core',
               'aurelia-kendoui-bridge'
           ],
       }`

   4. Imported the kendo-ui-core and aurelia-kendoui-bridge into the boot.ts file, and added the bridge plugin as per the installation instructions. boot.ts now looks like this (apologies for the dodgy formatting - for some reason it didn't want to apply code format to the whole block):

   `import 'isomorphic-fetch';`

   `import { Aurelia, PLATFORM } from 'aurelia-framework';`

   `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';`

   `import 'bootstrap';`

   `import 'kendo-ui-core';`

   `import 'aurelia-kendoui-bridge';`

   `declare const IS_DEV_BUILD: boolean;`
   `export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {`
       `aurelia.use.standardConfiguration()
           .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-kendoui-bridge'));`

   ```
   if (IS_DEV_BUILD) {
       aurelia.use.developmentLogging();
   }

   aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('app/components/app/app')));
   ```

   }

However when I run this I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: vendor_8b79c30b7e7439ee178d is not defined
    at Object.29 (external "vendor_8b79c30…"?f61b:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 162cab7…?2baa:657)
    at fn (bootstrap 162cab7…?2baa:85)
    at Object.126 (global.js from dll-reference vendor_8b79c30…?da06:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 162cab7…?2baa:657)
    at fn (bootstrap 162cab7…?2baa:85)
    at Object.7 (vendor.js?v=Filp3zKgThugnEmJ0hIhP507zLguUxBsJn0jDKuyf6c:68401)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 162cab7…?2baa:657)
    at fn (bootstrap 162cab7…?2baa:85)
    at Object.14 (aurelia-metadata.js?78b1:1)
```

My knowledge of Webpack and the Kendo Bridge is pretty basic so I may have missed some obvious steps here. Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong, and has anybody managed to get the Aurelia Kendo Bridge with the Aurelia .Net Core project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no longer an issue. Following the steps in the original question above now results in a working project.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `vendor-manifest.json` file which is used by webpack to reference vendor modules from the app bundle. You error means that this manifest does not match what's being exported from the vendor bundle

First couple on lines from my vendor bundle

```
var vendor_8b79c30b7e7439ee178d =
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
...
```

Beginning of my manifest

```
{"name":"vendor_8b79c30b7e7439ee178d",
```

There is a match in the name.

Rebuild of the vendor bundle followed by the app bundle rebuild should fix the issue.

```
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

**Also, aurelia template has a very significant bug which prevents reusability of the vendor bundle.** Make sure you look at [this PR](https://github.com/aspnet/templating/pull/16) for a fix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I retried all the steps listed in my question today on a new project and it seems to work fine now, so whatever the problem was it has been ironed out.